# Segregated Actions for post creation and update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to send HTTP requests when a POST is created, updated, or deleted. I was able to do this with taxonomies using the following actions:

- create_taxonomy
- edited_taxonomy
- delete_taxonomy

I am struggling to find a way to handle these operations as cleanly for posts. I need the operations:

- create -> send post HTTP request
- edit -> send put HTTP request
- delete -> send delete HTTP request

  ```
  function example_task_save( $post_ID, $post, $update ): void {
    // we only care about published tasks
    if ($post->post_type == 'example' && $post->post_status == 'publish') {
        $baseUrl = 'fake.url';
        $body = json_encode( formatTask( $post_ID ) );

        // determines if $post is updated or new
        if ( sizeof ( wp_get_post_revisions( $post ) )  > 1 ) {
            $url = $baseUrl . '/' . $post_ID;
            httpRequest( 'PUT', $url, $body );
        } else {
            httpRequest( 'POST', $baseUrl, $body );
        }
    }
  }

  add_action( 'save_post', 'example_task_save', 10, 3 );
  ```

I was attempting to use save_post to handle creation and edit, but this is less clean, and I would rather segregate these operations (create / edit) if possible. In order to tell whether the post existed or not I have been checking the revisions, which causes untrashed posts to trigger a PUT rather than a POST. Any tips on handling post creations and updates cleanly?